# Showing formulas in the text editor - Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

Is there an option to show the formulas in the text **editor** (not the PDF on the side) so that the text can be edited while the compiled formulas appear. This option exists in emax-auctex. Does it exist in editors like TeXstudio?

Answer (score 2):

Simply right-click the formula and choose "Preview Selection/Parentheses"

Note: for arbitrary environments you need to be at the beginning/end of a parenthesis. But for math formulas, you can click anywhere inside.

Comment: What I am looking for is to have the ENTIRE document compiled (that is, to see the compiled equations) but still to be able to edit the *text* (not the equations) in it , just like in auctex. What you suggested only work formula by formula (and also it shows the compiled formula after the formula code, I want the formula code to be replaced by the compiled formula).

Comment: this is not supported.