# Have equations in the script appear as they do once compiled

Tags: formatting, texstudio

I saw this online before and I was wondering if it is possible in TeXStudio.

The person had equations in their script appear as it would be in the pdf, unless either the cursor hovered over the script or the typing thing was there. Is this feature possible in TeXStudio?

Edit: I want the maths stuff to stay where it is in the script, but just appear as an equation and not as script.

Comment: Just put your typing cursor inside a math environment and press `alt+p`.

Comment: Thanks, that does show what it will look like, but I guess I didn't phrase my question very well then. I will edit it.

Comment: As per the comments of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214174/184389), what you want to achieve is not possible in TeXStudio.

Comment: @KersouMan how do I "undo" that alt+p? Pressing it again seems to do nothing.

Comment: Normally, if you right click on some text, you should see the option `Preview Selection/Parentheses` which is associated with the `alt+p` shortcut. Just below is the option to remove the preview (of which I don't know the name since my TeXStudio is in french). You can then associate a shortcut to this action.